# Express REST API authenticated on public access page

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

I know I can rely on basic-Auth if I want to ensure my api can be only accessed by right username and password.

How about let say I have a public access page (no username and password needed), and my api only open on the server that hosted the public access page. No one else able to access it.

Whats the right way to do this?

My current code below requires even the server to specify header for username and password.

```
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
var auth = function(req, res, next) {
var user = basicAuth(req);
if (!user || !user.name || !user.pass) {
    res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
    res.sendStatus(401);
    return;
}
if (user.name === 'user1' && user.pass === 'pass123') {
    next();
} else {
    res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
    res.sendStatus(401);
    return;
}
}

//Express call
app.get('/getCompany', auth, company.test);
```

Comment: "my api only open on the server that hosted the public access page. No one else able to access it." Can you clarify this?

Comment: I am creating an API for data to be displayed on a graph at the landing page. I dont want others to call this API and see the response. Unless from the server that hosted the app. Let me know if I need to explain further

Comment: The publicly visible pages can have its own route and serve HTML, JS, CSS files. All the API routes should have its own route something like GET /api/company/:id and all routes within /api require authentication. The public JS file can store the login token and use that to access the API resources, or you could use session. Storing name/pass on the JS side is not recommended.